# What is the proper way of importing a form in C#?

Tags: c#

i would like to import an existing form from visual studio 2010 into visual studio 2008.

all i want to do is create a new project in 2008
import form1 from 2010 and replace the existing one

what is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Copy-paste the .cs and .designer.cs files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy the `YourForm.cs` and `YourForm.designer.cs` into your 2008 project, and choose File->Add Existing Item.  Choose the `YourForm.cs` file.

It should come up automatically.

Be aware, however, that you may run into issues if you've used any code in your form that is specific to .NET 4.0.  Otherwise, it should work fine.